# How do I make Jasper Reports ignore newline characters in a text field?

Tags: java, csv, jasper-reports, newline

Whenever I export jasper report to CSV file, if a text field contains new line character, record inside CSV will be represented in two rows instead of one row.
Is there any setting that we can do inside jasper reports, which will make ignore the new line characters present in the text fields?
We use iReport to design jasper reports. Any kind of help is appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: You can use [net.sf.jasperreports.csv.record.delimiter](http://jasperforge.org/uploads/publish/jasp‌​erreportswebsite/trunk/config.reference.html#net.sf.jasperreports.csv.record.deli‌​miter) property for setting delimiter

Comment: I tried setting delimiter in java code.
`code`
JRPrintServiceExporter exporter = new JRPrintServiceExporter();
exporter.setParameter(JRCsvExporterParameter.RECORD_DELIMITER, "\r\n");
`code`
But it didn't work.

Comment: Did you use double quotes? You can read [this requirements for csv format](http://www.csvreader.com/csv_format.php)

Comment: Dear Alex, The present behavior I see is the field which has '\n' character, is coming in double quotes inside CSV file. I am not opening CSV file using xls. I need a way by which '\n' only at the end of record will be considered. If there is any '\n' character inside field, it should be ignored. Any hint would be appreciated.

Comment: Also when i checked the exact symbols using text editor, i see that after line there is a CR (\r) character and the field which had new line character, text editor shows that it has LF (line feed character).

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't really sound like a delimiter question to me. Your source data has a new line in it somewhere. JasperReports exports the data in the report, so it has this new line character.

It's analogous to having source data that reads, "abcdefg", and you say that you really hate the letter 'd', so you don't want it to appear in the generated CSV. Sure... new line is special in some respects... but it's still just a character.

You could modify the CSV exporter to strip out carriage returns (or to strip out 'd's). Or you could modify your query to strip them out. This would be simple if your source is SQL. Or you could modify your Text Field Expression to strip them out. For example, use [Apache Commons Lang StingUtils](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-3.0/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html) to delete or replace the new line character.

Comment: Dear mdahlman, the I tried stripping out new line character for that perticular column. It works. But we have many reports, and it is not practically possible to modify each and every column in each and every report. For exporting CSV we are not directly using JRCsvExporter. We are dependant on internal jasper report API.I was thinking if we could anyway extend JRCsvExporter and implement the require functionality. May be you can provide us more hints on this solution?

Comment: I haven't made an extension like that before. It's certainly possible... but I cannot estimate the effort. I would start by asking on the JasperReports forums. Or post it as a new question here. It's likely someone has done it before.